# I want to insert a gif on html and then move it using CSS to center it properly

Tags: html, css

I want to move a gif on css but it seems like only width and height is working. I cannot move the gif , to center it properly.Below is the piece of code and also an image of how the gif should look like            [image: gif image]

```
<img src="img/login.gif" width=20% alt="">
```

I use css code to move for it on page like

position : absolute;
right : 30%;

but it won't move, any advice

Comment: This should help: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: thanks you now I have been able to move the gif